# Openlayers and Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to use Openlayers to dynamically load features from my API into a Layer after my Map is loaded from within app.component.ts. My error is ***"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addFeature' of undefined"*** if I call my function from my app.component.ts on ngOnInit,

The source of my project was the following link although I've tried other examples without success. I cannot figure why my vectorSource object is NULL.

[Angular2 + Openlayers3: Test fails when map renders. Writing tests impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852037/angular2-openlayers3-test-fails-when-map-renders-writing-tests-impossible)

Below is the source code, I'm open to different designs or approaches to solve the issue. Thanks.

**ol.service.ts**

> ```
> import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
> import * as ol from 'openlayers';
>
>
> @Injectable()
> export class OlService {
>
>     get(): any {
>         return ol;
>     }
> }
> ```

**ol.component.ts**

> ```
> import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'; 
> import { OlService } from './ol.service';
>
> @Component({
>     selector: 'app-map',
>     providers: [OlService],
>     templateUrl: './ol.component.html',
>     styleUrls: ['./ol.component.css'],
>
> }) export class OlComponent implements OnInit {
>
>     @Input() lnglat: [number, number];
>     @Input() zoom: number;
>
>     private map;
>     public layers = [];
>     private vectorSource;
>
>     constructor(private olService: OlService) {
>
>         this.lnglat = [-93.49401, 45.08203];
>         this.zoom = 7;
>
>     }
>
>     createMap = () => {
>         let ol = this.olService.get();
>         this.vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
>         // define layers
>
>         let OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
>             source: new ol.source.OSM()
>         });
>         OSM.set('name', 'Openstreetmap');
>
>
>         let geography = new ol.layer.Tile({
>             source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
>                 url: '',
>                 crossOrigin: '',
>             }),
>             visible: false
>         });
>         geography.set('name', 'Geography');
>
>         let boundaries = new ol.layer.Tile({
>             opacity: 0.5,
>
>             source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
>                 url: '',
>                 params: {
>                     'LAYERS': 'fwsys:fwsys_region',
>                     'TILED': true,
>                     'transparent': 'true',
>                     'format': 'image/png'
>                 },
>                 serverType: 'geoserver',
>                 projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')
>             })
>         });
>         boundaries.set('name', 'Boundaries');
>         let vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
>             source: this.vectorSource
>         });
>
>         this.map = new ol.Map({
>             target: 'map',
>             layers: [OSM, geography, vector, boundaries],
>
>             view: new ol.View({
>                 center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(this.lnglat),
>                 zoom: this.zoom,
>                 projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')
>             })
>         });
>
>         let select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
>
>         this.map.addInteraction(select_interaction);
>
>         // add popup for all features
>         let container = document.getElementById('ol-popup');
>         let content = document.getElementById('ol-popup-content');
>         let closer = document.getElementById('ol-popup-closer');
>
>
>         let popup = new ol.Overlay({
>             element: container,
>             autoPan: true,
>             positioning: 'bottom-center',
>             stopEvent: false,
>             offset: [0, -5]
>         });
>
>         closer.onclick = function () {
>             popup.setPosition(undefined);
>             closer.blur();
>             return false;
>         };
>         this.map.addOverlay(popup);
>
>         this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
>             let feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, (feat) => {
>                 return feat;
>             });
>             if (feature) {
>                 let coordinate = evt.coordinate;
>                 content.innerHTML = feature.get('name');
>                 popup.setPosition(coordinate);
>             }
>
>
>         });
>         this.addLayerSwitcher([OSM, geography, boundaries]);
>         // This works during ngOnInit, but not after
>         this.addMarker([174.76, -37.10], 'Close to Auckland', 'akl1'); 
>         this.addMarker([173.76, -37.10], 'Out in in waters', 'pacific1');
>         // this.addMarker([38.909635, -77.043386], 'Dupont Circle', 'myid');
>
>         this.addPolygon([[174.76, -37.18], [176.76, -37.18], [176.76, -38.18], [174.76, -38.18]], 'Hamilton', 'id_hamilton');
>     };
>
>     addPolygon = (polygon: [[number, number]], name: string, id: string) => {
>         let ol = this.olService.get();
>         let projectedPolygon = [];
>
>         for (let poly of polygon) {
>             projectedPolygon.push(ol.proj.transform(poly, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
>         }
>
>         let p = new ol.geom.Polygon([projectedPolygon]);
>
>         let featurething = new ol.Feature({
>             name: name,
>             id: id,
>             geometry: p
>         });
>
>         this.vectorSource.addFeature(featurething);
>
>     };
>
>
>     setMarker(coords: [number, number], name: string, id: string) {
>
>         this.addMarker(coords, name, id);
>     }
>
>     addMarker = (coords: [number, number], name: string, id: string) => {
>         
>         let ol = this.olService.get();
>         let iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
>             geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(coords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
>             name: name,
>             id: id,
>         });
>
>         let iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
>             image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */({
>                 opacity: 0.75,
>                 anchor: [0.5, 1],
>                 src: '//cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/location-alt-32.png'
>             }))
>         });
>
>         iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
>         //
>         // THIS CODE FAILS BECAUSE "this.vectorSource." is null when
>         // addMarker() is called after ngOnInit() from app.component.ts
>         //
>         this.vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
>
>     }
>
>     addLayerSwitcher = (layers: [any]) => {
>
>         this.layers = layers;
>
>     }
>     toggleLayer = (layer, evt) => {
>         evt.target.blur();
>         if (layer.getVisible()) {
>             layer.setVisible(false);
>
>         } else {
>             layer.setVisible(true);
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     ngOnInit() {
>         this.createMap();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

**app.component.ts**

> ```
> import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
>
> import { OlComponent } from './_component/ol.component';
> import {OlService} from './_component/ol.service';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-root',
>   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
>   providers: [OlComponent, OlService]
> })
> export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
>   title = 'app works!';
>
>
>   constructor(private olcomponent: OlComponent) {
>     // constructor
>   }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>   // I WANT TO ADD MARKERS after the ol.component.ngOnInit() from an
>   // outside API service - THIS CODE FAILS due to a null vectorSource 
>   // object. 
>   this.olcomponent.setMarker([38.909635, -77.043386], 'Dupont Circle', 'myid');  
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: After researching the issue more, it seems to be related to ngOnInit() and the LifeCycle Hooks, See link below.  What I discovered was the app.component.ts fires ngOnInit() before the ol.component.ts ngOnInit(). Since the app.component.ts fires first, my object "vectorSource" would have not been created yet. I would believe this to be true with any object you tried to use regardless of Openlayers being involved. So how do you build a component and access at the same time? Is this a good case for a Promise? if so, then how?
 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html